# Eclipse for netbooks - what an I do to enhance performance on linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, ide

My main development environment on my Windows machine uses Eclipse and I'm quite happy with it. I sync all my projects into SVN and want to be able to work on projects at coffee shops without lugging my real laptop around. Problem is that my netbook is pretty low scale - it's one of the first EEE pcs and right now it is supposedly "overclocked" and still laggy. I'm running Xubuntu. Anyway, is there any build of Eclipse that is optimized or geared towards low end hardware on Linux?

I have heard about Netbeans but I've never tried it and while it wouldn't be the end of the world it would be a bit tiresome switching over my projects (possibly?). I'd assume it would be faster, though, but I'm really used to Eclipse and the plugins I've been using.

Comment: I don't know much about EEE pc's.Can you upgrade RAM on those?

Answer (score 1):

Your probably out of luck with those specs (the original EEEpc was pretty underpowered to run something like eclipse)

I would suggest instead, use the command line with svn/ant/jdb/vim :) Your machine will be able to handle that as opposed to a full blown eclipse IDE. Also you don't have much screen real estate do you? Again using the CLI only will help in that department

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans takes *forever* to start up compared to Eclipse, and feels more sluggish, so I don't think I'd head that way...

I run both Eclipse and Netbeans on an MSI Wind under XP and Eclipse actually runs quite nicely- thats w/ a 1.6GHz atom cpu. I think your problem is purely (lack of) CPU horsepower if you're running the 900MHz Celeron. And you probably don't have even a GB of RAM so that's another problem.

I don't think a special build of Eclipse is available that will get around your speed problems on that particular netbook...

Comment: hm, I think that before you start bashing on netbeans based on subjective experience - however correct they may be - you should link to performance comparisons. Or provide your own.

Comment: I agree with Steen.   I saw no difference starting either application, and would actually say the newest JRE/netbeans release is quicker than previous netbeans on startup.   I personally run a EeePC 900HA, and like everything about it except programming on the small keyboard.  In a pinch it is a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:
http://www.geek.com/articles/chips/eee-pc-chronicles-part-3-memory-upgrade-20071231/

Seems like you can upto 1gb with linux(Xandros)
and upto 2gb if you install windowx xp or a differnt flavor of linux instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Ubuntu Netbook Remix. I have been using it on an ACER AOD150 and its great.